# Find $\operatorname{Corr}(XY,Y)$ and $\operatorname{Corr}(X^{2},Y^{2})$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$\def\Cov{\operatorname{Cov}}\def\Corr{\operatorname{Corr}}\def\Var{\operatorname{Var}}$
Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ have a joint normal distribution with $E(X)=E(Y)=0, \Var(X)=\Var(Y)=1, \Corr(X,Y)=\rho$, how can I find $\Corr(XY,Y)$ and $\Corr(X^{2},Y^{2})$

I have no idea how to compute them, does anyone could help me? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know that $\operatorname{corr}(XY,Y)=\dfrac{\operatorname{cov}(XY,Y)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{var}(XY)\operatorname{var}(Y)}}$?  If not, then you must have run into difficulty after you wrote that down and thought about how to evaluate it.  But you haven't told us that, and you should have.  If you _don't_ know that that's how correlation is defined, then the way out of your difficulty begins with learning that.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I know the formula, but I cannot find $Cov(XY,Y)$

Comment: More generally, for $Cov(X Y, Y)$, see also:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116535/correlation-of-product-of-uncorrelated/

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2926888/321264

Answer (score 1):

$\def\cov{\operatorname{cov}}\def\corr{\operatorname{corr}}\def\var{\operatorname{var}}\def\E{\operatorname{E}}$
$$
\cov(XY,Y) = \E(XY^2)-\E(XY)\E(Y) = \E(XY^2) = \E(\E(XY^2\mid Y)) = \E(Y^2\E(X\mid Y)).
$$
So we need to know that $\E(X\mid Y) = \rho Y$.  Then you have $\rho\E(Y^3) = 0$.

With the bivariate normal distribution you have
$$
\E\left(\frac{X-\mu_X}{\sigma_X} \mid Y\right) = \rho \left( \frac{Y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y} \right).
$$
Is that something you've seen before?

Comment: Why $XY^{2}$ becomes $XY$ after using the law of total expectations?

Comment: What I did is keeping $XY^{2}$ remaining

Comment: Sorry --- that was a typo.

Comment: Alright, now I know what mistake I have made, but why $E(Y^{3})=0$? I have no idea how to compute it, thanks again

Comment: The distribution of $Y^3$ is identical to that of $-Y^3$; hence its expectation is $0$, provided only that $\operatorname{E}(|Y^3|)<\infty$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: It's really helpful, thanks again.