# Find $ \operatorname{Cov}(X^2,Y^2)$

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ follow $N(0,1)$ and $ \operatorname{Corr}(X,Y)=\rho$. Find $  \operatorname{Cov}(X^2,Y^2)$.

Here is what I know 
$$ \operatorname{Cov}(X^2,Y^2)=E[X^2Y^2]-E[X^2]E[Y^2]$$
Since $E[X^2]= \operatorname{Var}(X)+E^2[X]= \operatorname{Var}(X)$, 
 $\enspace E[X^2]E[Y^2]= \operatorname{Var}(X) \operatorname{Var}(Y)=1$.
But I don't know how to deal with $E[X^2Y^2]$.
Am I in the right track?

Comment: To say that $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y\sim N(0,1)$ and $\operatorname{corr}(X,Y) = \text{a particular number}$ is not enough information to specify the distribution of the pair $(X,Y).$ However, it is enough  if you add an additional bit of information: that the pair $(X,Y)$ is JOINTLY normally distributed. There is this simple way of getting $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y\sim N(0,1)$ and $\operatorname{corr}(X,Y) = \text{your preferred number}$ without $(X,Y)$ being jointly normal: Let $Y=\begin{cases} \phantom{+}X&\text{if } |X|\le c, \\ -X&\text{if }|X| > c, \end{cases}\quad$ and then$\,\ldots \qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$ choose the value of $c$ to to make the correlation what you want it to be. $\qquad$

Comment: I don't know whether or not the information given, without the assumption of JOINT normality, is enough to determine the correlation between $X^2$ and $Y^2. \qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean $(X,Y)$ is jointly normal where $X$ and $Y$ have zero means and unit variances and $\operatorname{Corr}(X,Y)=\rho$, we know the conditional distribution of $Y\mid X$, namely

$$Y\mid X\sim N(\rho X,1-\rho^2)$$

Then using the law of total expectation,

\begin{align}
E(X^2Y^2)&=E\left[E(X^2Y^2\mid X)\right]
\\&=E\left[X^2E(Y^2\mid X)\right]
\\&=E\left[X^2\left(\operatorname{Var}(Y\mid X)+(E(Y\mid X))^2\right)\right]
\\&=\quad\cdots
\end{align}